# Why doesn't Xcode provide autocompletion for dot-notated properties on objects of type id<protocol>?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Given this protocol definition:

```
@protocol MyProtocol <NSObject>
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *someProperty;
@end
```

Why will Xcode gladly offer autocompletion for this statement:

```
id<MyProtocol> thing = [ThingManager currentThing];
[thing someProperty]; // Xcode offered autocompletion here
```

But it doesn't offer autocompletion when I try to access the *same* property using dot-notation:

```
id<MyProtocol> thing = [ThingManager currentThing];
thing.someProperty; // Xcode claimed there were 
                    // "No completions" available
                    // after the period
```

Comment: Because id is a base-type, and protocols don't actually add methods or properties to the classes that claim to implement them (`<>` ain't there for nothing!), Xcode shouldn't actually provide an auto-completion for the property.  In fact, the only reason the method syntax was autocompleted is because Xcode appears to pool together all methods, regardless of type, for the objects that are imported into a given file (again, because id is a base type, and therefore, should be able to successfully handle a call to at least one of those methods)

Comment: @CodaFi you are absolutely right. You should post this comment as an answer

Comment: @CodaFi : I cant do +1 for your comment, this shouldn't be here...its place is in Answers section.

Comment: in AppCode i don't worry about this :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `id` is a base type, Xcode and CLANG are uneasy about providing dot-syntax access against it because dot syntax is just syntactic sugar for a method call to an associated setter or getter in a normal object, but id has no defined method members.  Looking at it from the C side of things, id is a typedef for a struct pointer that the compiler cannot see the members of, which means it cannot access them (never mind the fact that you would need to dereference id before dot-access would make any semantic sense).

Back to the Objective-C side of things, protocols don't actually add methods or properties to the classes that claim to implement them, rather they serve as a specifier to other classes that an object that conforms to a given protocol *implements* a series of methods.  As for the method-syntax being completed, Xcode pools all of the given methods of all the files imported into a given .m file because, an object of type id can receive any message*

*<sub>of course, it can receive the message, but it'll still crash if it's unimplemented.</sub>

Comment: So Xcode is skittish about providing autocompletion for entities of type `id`, even if I specify a protocol. Is that why, if I have `[ThingManager currentThing]` return an `NSObject<MyProtocol>` instead, Xcode offers autocompletion gladly?

Comment: @steveluscher because you can't add properties to id (it's a typedef for a struct), but you can to an object!

Comment: But you can send messages to a 'struct' and therefore autocomplete them? It's clearly a shortcoming in Xcode's autocompletion.

Comment: While this answer is helpful, I don't think it really explains why Xcode can't autocomplete. I agree with @StevenKramer – if the dot syntax is simply syntactic sugar, Xcode should recognize the getter-style form of invoking the method, and it should autocomplete.

Comment: @akivag29 id is, to the language, a C construct, not an Objective-C one.  Dot-syntax is struct member access in C rather than a message send, and thus makes no sense considering id is a reference type.

Comment: @CodaFi but you can send (auto-completed) messages to the C construct. And the C construct doesn't support "C" member access dot syntax, because it is in fact a pointer. And the C construct is magically reference counted by ARC. You raise some valid points, but it would be nice if someone at Apple was reading this and would just fix the problem with the IDE. I'm now resorting to `NSObject<Adopted>*` where `id<Adopted>` would have sufficed just for the benefit of auto-completion.

Comment: You can send anything a message, that doesn't mean you won't Bork the runtime doing it.  The issue here is convenience versus semantics.  You wish you could invoke nullary messages on id, but to do so would mean allowing you to use dot syntax with everything ending in -Ref in CoreFoundation, CoreGraphics, etc.  Being a strict superset of C means you don't get to mess with it.

Answer (score 2):

This is kind of a tangential answer, and a thought experiment.

But before that, I'll note that you could get your property autocomplete by skipping `id`, like this:

```
NSObject<MyProtocol> *thing;
thing.▮
```

But assuming you don't want the entire list of `NSObject` methods gumming up your completion, you *could* do something like

```
EmptyClass<MyProtocol> *thing = [ThingManager currentThing];

// completion list will be (close) to only the protocol props
thing.▮
```

`EmptyClass` serves a similar "OK, no promises!" role that `id` does, but autocomplete likes it. Here's `EmptyClass`:

```
NS_ROOT_CLASS
@interface EmptyClass

@end

@implementation EmptyClass

+ (void)initialize {} // required

@end
```

Mind you, the object in `thing` is not actually rooted on `EmptyClass` (*can't* be), so this is high fakery. However, it

- *vastly underpromises* what `thing` can actually do.
- doesn't (**can't!**) instantiate an `EmptyClass` object.

So why not? If you try *really* hard, you can cause problems like

```
EmptyClass *nooooo = [[NSClassFromString(@"EmptyClass") alloc] init];
```

which will immediately exception. But not really a tricky bug to avoid.

A gotcha wouldn't surprise me, but I don't know one right now. Please, leave a comment if you do.

Comment: Why not just use `NSObject<MyProtocol> *thing`?  The probability that steveluscher is using a class not derived from `NSObject` is rather small.

Comment: @robmayoff Edited answer to be clearer, thanks. Should answer your question.